# How to rewrite duplicate keys in dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, comparison

I need to get data from `HttpContext` collections and store it in one `Dictionary`, but I have a problem. How can I rewrite `KeyValuePair` in `Dictionary` if I meet pair with key which `Dictionary` already has?

For example, my function:

```
private static IDictionary<string, object> FromNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection rq)
{
return (from string query in rq
        select new KeyAndValue { Key = query, Value = (object)rq[query] })
        .ToDictionary(ExtractKey, ExtractValue, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

`KeyAndValue` is my special class looks like KeyValuePair, but it has field `CollectionName` - Indicates the source collection (`QueryString`, `Form` or `Headers`) my value comes from.

```
class KeyAndValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string CollectionName { set; get; }
}
```

And

```
private static string ExtractKey(KeyAndValue kvp)
{
    return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Key) ? kvp.ColName : kvp.Key);
}

private static string ExtractValue(KeyAndValue kvp)
{
    return kvp.Value;
}
```

I suspect that I dont understand what `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` is, and how does it work. Or... I dont understand how to use it right! So, I need help.

Thanks!

Comment: The whole purpose of a dictionary is that its keys are unique. Use a dictionary with List values like `Dictionary<key, List<object>>`.

Comment: @RedSerpent Thats why I use dictionary. But my sources are `NameValueCollections`, as I said. `ILookUp` not good for me. My output data must be only `Dictionary <string, object>`.

Comment: `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` does exactly what it announces: compares strings in a linguistically relevant manner that ignores case, but it is not suitable for display in any particular culture. Its major application is to order strings in a way that will be identical across cultures. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z3e2ccx2.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override Equals and GetHashCode on your class KeyAndValue because the Dictionary will compare references and not the values that you wish to.

Answer (score 3):

Simple... don't use a Dictionary, and instead consider making an [ILookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. It's pretty much the same as a Dictionary other than it allows for the storing of multiple values against a key. So...

```
(from string query in rq
    select new KeyAndValue { Key = query, Value = (object)rq[query] })
    .ToLookup(ExtractKey, ExtractValue, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Given your comments, a bit of prefiltering to take only the last value for a particular key...

```
rq.Select(query => new KeyAndValue { Key = query, Value = (object)rq[query] })
  .GroupBy(kav => kav.Key)
  .Select(g => new KeyAndValue {Key = g.Key, Value = g.Last()})
  .ToDictionary(...
```

Comment: I need strictly related pairs, so my output data must be only `IDictionary<string, object>`. I asked how to **rewrite** `KeyValuePair` in current dictionary

Comment: @Matterai So, how do you propose dealing with your duplicate keys? Dictionary can't deal with this. It's 1 key, 1 value. That's what a Dictionary is. Either you have to throw values away, or deal with this another way.

Comment: If I meet in dictionary pair with the same key, I want to write new value, thats all I want =)

Comment: Sorry but @AlexPeta's offer is better for my solution! Thank you!